# A start job is running for ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I have installed a Oracle Virtual box on Windows 10 machine. In Virtual box, I was trying to install Ubuntu 16.04. After getting a message 'Install Complete', I was asked to restart the machine but instead I got a message '**A start job is running for ubuntu l...D installer (1min 6s / no limit)**' on black screen. I waited for around 10-15 minutes but this message remained on the screen. And then I closed the virtual box as I was clueless on how to proceed further.

It would be great if community can tell me the reason behind this and how I can get rid of it in order to start working on Ubuntu OS. Best regards for your help in advance.

Comment: do you have vistrualisation (VT-d) enabled on your PC? what is your cpu exact model (don't tell me "i7" , tell me something like "3990x")

Comment: Virtualization is not enabled in my PC and I had tried this a bit but could not do so. Therefore I tried to install 32-bit ubuntu desktop version on Virtual machine instead of 64 bit version. CPU model number is 'B830'. Thanks for your help. I am stuck in this issue for 3-4 days.

Comment: hmm. maybe try with another build of ubuntu maybe the server build or the lowlatency. and in virtualbox's configuration for that virtual machine make sure Virtualization is turned off, you may also have to turn on 3D acceleration.

Comment: Thanks @tatsu for your help. Now I am getting 'Grub Menu' options. Then I selected  'Advanced option for ubuntu' Then selected 'ubuntu with recovery mode'. Then system boot. A 'welcome to ubuntu 16.04 LTS' message came. Then  in recovery menu, it asks user to choose one of multiple options like normal boot, drop to root shell prompt etc. Please let me know what to select and what further actions required.

Comment: i don't know why not "normal boot"

Comment: I selected normal install from 'Recovery Menu'. And by grace of GOD and your valuable guidance I am able to see Ubuntu screen. Great Thanks @tastu.

Comment: I will provide an answer for other people to benefit. make sure to mark it! I'm glad to have helped ! :) for the record, what fixed it? I think it was the virtualbox option "3D acceleration"  I don't think "virtualization" was on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend turnin on the "3D acceleration" option under "graphics"  tab in that virtual machine's configuration in virtual box because your hardware does not support VT-d so instead of that you should use "3D acceleration".